# Center a UI element in Android

Tags: android, imageview, center

I am looking for a way to center a UI element in android. Specifically the ImageView. Since I know the image I will be displaying isn't as wide as the screen I need to center it! Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Just put in into a Layout, like LinearLayout which has a width like "fill_parent" and for the ImageView itself define android:gravity = "center"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can position the imageview within a relative layout. Set the layout properties for your image using these:

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

Comment: Make sure that the parent RelativeLayout fills the space in which you want to center the image.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to center an imageView in the layout , use layout_gravity , (if its linear layout)
If you are talking about an image inside the imageView , use android:scaleType in xml of imageView